# Wix error - Windows Installer Hot Fix 981669

Tags: wix

We have an issue in our product installation in XP OS with Windows Installer 4.5 & it’s Hot Fix 981669. The installation is prematurely ending.

> Error 1719: The Windows Installer Service could not be accessed.

Without that Hot Fix we are able to install the application.

There are several pages on the web talking about problems with the Windows Installer, but no real answers as to how to solve the problem. For example, [here, in method 2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315346) they are asking to reinstall windows installer. I suggested this as a workaround for the issue.

The Windows Installer Hot Fix 981669, is replacing two DLLs: msi.dll & Msihnd.dll.

After  Windows Installer Hot Fix 981669:

```
msi.dll [version 4.5.6002.22362]
Msihnd.dll [version 4.5.6002.22193]
```

Before it was:

```
msi.dll [version 4.5.6001.22159]
Msihnd.dll [version 4.5.6001.22159]
```

With original versions of Windows Installer 4.5 DLLs (msi.dll [version 4.5.6001.22159] and Msihnd.dll [version 4.5.6001.22159]) we are able to install the product without any issues.

We are using WIX (Votive-2.0.5805.0.msi) application to create the product MSI.

If you have any idea about this issue please help.

Comment: Do you have xp sp3 installed?  Did you reboot after installing the hotfix?  Can you post the setup installation log file?  What custom action causes the issue?  Do you have multiple packages in your msi?

Comment: If you don't have strong reasons to keep that hotfix, why wouldn't you just uninstall it?

Comment: Run msi from command prompt with log. Check the log file. it might help you a lot. Also post the log file here.